# Unable to sign in with phone number unless phone number is added as an optional testing number

Tags: firebase, android-studio, react-native

When I try to register as a user using my react-native app I get the following error.

Sing In With Phone Number Error: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [App validation failed.]

In my Firebase project settings I created a new app, generated a signing report( In android studio) and added the SHA-1 and SHA-256 values from that to Firebase. I then used the new google-services.json file in my project.

Update:
I also tried using keytool and updated the SHA-1 and SHA-256 in Firebase.

keytool.exe -list -v -alias key0 -keystore ks.jks

No luck with any of this so far.

Comment: Please share the code so that we can run the error ourselves and see the error.

Comment: There really isn’t any code that is throwing the error. It’s more of a setup type issue between the code base and fire base. I’m looking for someone that’s familiar with the error message in hopes of finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. The SHA-1 needs to come from the play console not your local machine.